# I am getting lsapi:error and it is causing 503 error

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

The following error is being triggered:
[Wed Oct 19 00:46:51.328670 2022] [lsapi:error] [pid 8996:tid 47089191048960] [client 193.111.60.5:0] [host] Error receiving response header (lsphp is killed?): ReceiveResponseHeader: receive pkg hdr failed: ReceivePkgHdr: nothing to read from backend (LVE ID 1001), check http://docs.cloudlinux.com/mod_lsapi_troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

I added memory limit 4095M which solve this error